# Java hashmap from python dict command?

Tags: java, parsing

I have a weird problem that I don't fully understand how to solve.  Could someone please give me some pointers on hashmaps?

I have a variable:

```
/servlet/charting?base_color=grey&amp;chart_width=288&amp;chart_height=160&amp;chart_type=png&amp;chart_style=manufund_pie&amp;3DSet=true&amp;chart_size=small&amp;leg_on=left&amp;static_xvalues=10.21,12.12,43.12,12.10,&amp;static_labels=blue,red,green,purple"
```

I basically want 10.21,12.12,43.12,12.10 to be associated with blue,red,green,purple (in the order displayed)

In python I created a method that does this with:

```
def stripChart(name):
    name = str(name)
    name = urlparse.urlparse(name)
    name = cgi.parse_qs(name.query)
    name = dict(zip( name['static_labels'][0].split(','), name['static_xvalues'][0].split(',')))
```

Not sure how to do this in java.  So far I have:

```
URL imgURL = new URL (imgTag);
String[] result = imgURL.getFile().split("&");
 for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
     System.out.println(result[x]);
```

This gives me:

```
chart_width=288
chart_height=160
chart_type=png
chart_style=manufund_pie
3DSet=true
chart_size=small
leg_on=left
static_xvalues=10.21,12.12,43.12,12.10,
static_labels=blue,red,green,purple,
```

At this point I'm confused how to link static_labels and static_xvalues values.

Thanks so much. Any pointers would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Something like this (assuming you stored the labels into the String 'static_labels' and the values in the String 'static_xvalues'):

```
HashMap<String, Double> colorMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
StringTokenizer labelTok = new StringTokenizer(static_labels, ",");
StringTokenizer valuesTok = new StringTokenizer(static_xvalues, ",");
while(labelTok.hasMoreElements()){
  assert(valuesTok.hasMoreElements());
  colorMap.put(labelTok.nextElement(), Double.parseDouble(valuesTok.nextElement()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using java.util.HashMap.  Let's say you have stored the static_xvalues and static_labels request parameters into corresponding string variables.  Something like the following will create the mapping for you:

```
String[] vals = static_xvalues.split(",");
String[] labels = static_labels.split(",");
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
for (int i=0; i <  vals.length; ++i) {
  map.put(labels[i], values[i]);
}
```

You do not say if the xvalues need to be stored as floats or not.  If so, you will need to convert the vals array into a Float (or Double) array first, and modify the HashMap instantiation accordingly:

```
HashMap<String,Float> = new HashMap<String,Float>();
```